# Creating a Dynamic Menu

Tags: css, asp.net, dynamic, menu, html-lists

I want to created a vertical dynamic menu with menu items that pop when needed. For example, menu has all country names and when you roll over a country, sub menu city names becomes visible.  I chose the UL method to do this.  So far I can make the menu list etc, but I have no idea how to make the sub menus visible and hide on roll over of country.  Here is the code I got.

```
        qString = "SELECT t.cID, t.cCountry, t.cPlace, t.cRating FROM tplaces AS t ORDER BY t.cCountry ASC, t.cPlace";

        dtMenuPlaces = GetTable(qString);

        int placeMenuWidth = 130;
        int placeMenuHeight = 40;

        if (dtMenuPlaces != null)
        {
            int menuY = 0;

            string previousCountry = "";
            int previousBGColor = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();

            string fnMenuBG = "blankblockBlue";

            HtmlGenericControl mainLI = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlGenericControl subUL = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");

            for (int x = 0; x < dtMenuPlaces.Rows.Count; x++)
            {

                int rnMenuBG = rand.Next(1, arrayMenuButtonNames.Length) - 1;
                int cPlaceID = Convert.ToInt32(dtMenuPlaces.Rows[x][0]);
                string cCountry = dtMenuPlaces.Rows[x][1].ToString();
                string cPlace = dtMenuPlaces.Rows[x][2].ToString();
                int cRating = Convert.ToInt32(dtMenuPlaces.Rows[x][3]);

                string tempUrl = cCountry + cPlace + ".aspx";

                tempUrl = tempUrl.Replace(" ", "");

                tempUrl += "?fVar1=place&" + "fVar2=" + cPlace + "&fVar3=" + cCountry;

                System.Text.StringBuilder tString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                // used to make multiline buttons.

                if (cPlace != "")
                {
                    //  tString.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    tString.AppendLine(cPlace);
                }
                else
                {

                    tString.AppendLine(cCountry);
                }

                if (previousCountry != cCountry)
                {

                    rnMenuBG = rand.Next(1, arrayMenuButtonNames.Length) - 1;

                    while (rnMenuBG == previousBGColor)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Random -  #" + rnMenuBG + " P " + previousBGColor);
                        rnMenuBG = rand.Next(1, arrayMenuButtonNames.Length) - 1;


                    }

                    fnMenuBG = "blankblock" + arrayMenuButtonNames[rnMenuBG];

                    mainLI = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                    menuPlaces.Controls.Add(mainLI);

                    HtmlGenericControl mainA = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    mainA.Attributes.Add("href", tempUrl);
                    mainA.InnerText = tString.ToString();
                    //    mainA.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "mainLI.style.display='none'");
                    //    mainA.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "mainLI.style.display='block'");
                    mainA.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration: none;width:" + placeMenuWidth + "px;height:" + placeMenuHeight + "px;line-height:" + placeMenuHeight + "px;");
                    mainLI.Controls.Add(mainA);

                    subUL = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
                    mainLI.Controls.Add(subUL);
                    mainLI.ID = "mainList";

                    previousCountry = cCountry;
                    previousBGColor = rnMenuBG;

                    //  mainLI.Style["Background-image"] = "url:('images/gfx/" + fnMenuBG + ".gif'); no-repeat;";
                    mainLI.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;position:absolute;top:" + menuY + "px;font-size:14px;font-family:century gothic;text-align: center;font-weight:bold;background:url('images/gfx/" + fnMenuBG + ".gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;");
                    //  mainLI.Attributes.Add("style", "background:url('images/gfx/" + fnMenuBG + ".gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;");

                    menuY += placeMenuHeight + 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    rnMenuBG = previousBGColor;

                    fnMenuBG = "blankblock" + arrayMenuButtonNames[rnMenuBG];

                    /// add SUB place if not main country.
                    HtmlGenericControl subLI = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                    subUL.Controls.Add(subLI);

                    subUL.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;position:relative;top:-" + placeMenuHeight + "px;left:" + placeMenuWidth + "px;margin: 0px; padding:0px;width:" + placeMenuWidth + "px;list-style-type:none;");

                    HtmlGenericControl subA = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    subA.Attributes.Add("href", tempUrl);
                    // subA.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.color=\"red\"");
                    //  subA.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.color=\"black\"");
                    // subA.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.color=\"yellow\"");
                    subA.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration: none;display:block;width:" + placeMenuWidth + "px;height:" + placeMenuHeight + "px;line-height:" + placeMenuHeight + "px;");
                    subA.InnerText = tString.ToString();
                    subLI.Controls.Add(subA);

                    //  subLI.Style["Background-image"] = "url:('images/gfx/" + fnMenuBG + ".gif'); no-repeat;";
                    subLI.Attributes.Add("style", "width:" + placeMenuWidth + "px;height:" + placeMenuHeight + "px;margin:0px;margin-bottom:5px;;padding:0px;font-size:14px;font-family:century gothic;text-align: center;font-weight:bold;background:url('images/gfx/" + fnMenuBG + ".gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;");

                    //  subLI.Attributes.Add("style", "font-size:14px;font-family:century gothic;text-align: center;font-weight:bold");
                    // subLI.Attributes.Add("style", "background:url('images/gfx/" + fnMenuBG + ".gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;");

                }

            }
        }
```

Also is it better to create HTMLGENERICCONTROLS or adding literal controls to a string builder?

Comment: something like this http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/ ??

Comment: But using behind code C# to create menu as I create the menu from information from a Database.  I just don't know how to make sub menus hide/show when mouseover or mouseout

Comment: are u fine using Jquery ?the mouseover or mouseout will have to be done using Javascript or Jquery . i guess

Answer (score 1):

heres a snippet of Jquery that might help you for the mouseover and mouseout, i picked it from a Jquery plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var el = $('li');
                var hidden_ul = $('.hidden')
                el.on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
                    $(this).find('.hidden').css({'display' : 'block'});
                    e.type == 'mouseout' &&  $(this).find('.hidden').css({'display' : 'none'});
                });  //---------------------------- End on function.    
            });
```

I have constructed a simple responsive menu , which might help you understand , what i mean as a whole check out the fiddle below :

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzbjfo77/)

incase you are not comfortable with Jquery , just remove the Jquery code and add the following peice of CSS in the stylesheet :

```
ul li a:hover + ul ,.hidden:hover{
    display: block;
}
```

The original menu i build was intended to be CSS only , but i am giving you both a CSS as well as a Jquery solution , you can pick whichever one is more suited to you. :)

Cheers.

Comment: I was close to getting to work with HTMLGENERIC method, but I decided to rewrite the whole thing using stringbuilder and it worked.  adding like u said to main.css plus in C#

Comment: @ColinKozik did my solution help in the least bit ?

Answer (score 0):

I was close to getting to work with HTMLGENERIC method, but I decided to rewrite the whole thing using stringbuilder and it worked. adding like u said to main.css plus in C#.

System.Text.StringBuilder sbMenu = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

```
        qString = "SELECT t.cID, t.cCountry, t.cPlace, t.cRating FROM tplaces AS t ORDER BY t.cCountry ASC, t.cPlace";

        dtMenuPlaces = GetTable(qString);

        if (dtMenuPlaces != null)
        {

            string previousCountry = "";
            int previousBGColor = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();

            string fnMenuBG = "blankblockBlue";

        //    HtmlGenericControl mainLI = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        //    HtmlGenericControl subUL = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");

            for (int x = 0; x < dtMenuPlaces.Rows.Count; x++)
            {

                int rnMenuBG = rand.Next(1, arrayMenuButtonNames.Length) - 1;
                int cPlaceID = Convert.ToInt32(dtMenuPlaces.Rows[x][0]);
                string cCountry = dtMenuPlaces.Rows[x][1].ToString();
                string cPlace = dtMenuPlaces.Rows[x][2].ToString();
                int cRating = Convert.ToInt32(dtMenuPlaces.Rows[x][3]);

                string tempUrl = cCountry + cPlace + ".aspx";

                tempUrl = tempUrl.Replace(" ", "");

                tempUrl += "?fVar1=place&" + "fVar2=" + cPlace + "&fVar3=" + cCountry;

                System.Text.StringBuilder tString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                // used to make multiline buttons.

                if (cPlace != "")
                {
                    //  tString.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    tString.AppendLine(cPlace);
                }
                else
                {

                    tString.AppendLine(cCountry);
                   if (x != 0)
                    {
                        sbMenu.Append("</ul>");
                    }

                }


                if (previousCountry != cCountry)
                {

                    rnMenuBG = rand.Next(1, arrayMenuButtonNames.Length) - 1;

                    while (rnMenuBG == previousBGColor)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Random -  #" + rnMenuBG + " P " + previousBGColor);
                        rnMenuBG = rand.Next(1, arrayMenuButtonNames.Length) - 1;


                    }

                    fnMenuBG = "blankblock" + arrayMenuButtonNames[rnMenuBG];

                    sbMenu.Append("<li class='subMenuPlaces' style = background:url('images/gfx/" + fnMenuBG + ".gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;><a href='" + tempUrl + "'>" + tString.ToString() + "</a><ul class='subList'>");

                    previousCountry = cCountry;
                    previousBGColor = rnMenuBG;       

                }
                else
                {
                    rnMenuBG = previousBGColor;

                    fnMenuBG = "blankblock" + arrayMenuButtonNames[rnMenuBG];

                    sbMenu.Append("<li class='subMenuPlaces' style = background:url('images/gfx/" + fnMenuBG + ".gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;><a href='" + tempUrl + "'>" + tString.ToString() + "</a></li>");

                }

            }
            menuPlaces.InnerHtml = sbMenu.ToString();

        }
```